# NoClassDefFoundError at opening Dynamic Module

Tags: android, applozic, dynamic-feature, dynamic-feature-module

Suppose I have created an Android project `AwesomeApp`. Then I need to add chatting functionality to this App. So that, I have created another project to build an SDK for chatting. The output of my chat SDK are 4 `aar` files. These `aar` files contain another chat SDK of `Applozic`.

Then I have successfully integrated 4 `aar` files to my `AwesomeApp` and everything is going fine. But the `aar` files are too large. So I have decided to use Android's new dynamic delivery feature.

To do so, I have created new project. In manifest file I've mention application name like this `android:name="com.google.android.play.core.splitcompat.SplitCompatApplication"`. In this project I have created a dynamic module `chat-module`.  Inside this dynamic module I have created an activity `DynamicActivity` and added those 4 `aar` files. From `DynamicActivity` I call the chat feature (of aar file) by clicking on an icon.

I can successfully download the `chat-module` and open `DynamicActivity` of `chat-module` dynamic module. But when I click on the icon of `DynamicActivity` to open/initialize chat feature - the app has crashed. Crash report:

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:390)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6304)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24803)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:794)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6651)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:824)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6304) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24803) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:794) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6651) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:824) 
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/applozic/mobicomkit/Applozic;
        at com.example.chatapp.utility.ChitChat.initialize(ChitChat.java:83)
        at com.example.chatapp_dynamic_module.DynamicActivity.startSecondPerson(DynamicActivity.java:53)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6304) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24803) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:794) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6651) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:824) 
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.applozic.mobicomkit.Applozic" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.applab-aoTGwb4UiExHn2UP-1ioGA==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.applab-aoTGwb4UiExHn2UP-1ioGA==/split_config.en.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.applab-aoTGwb4UiExHn2UP-1ioGA==/split_config.xhdpi.apk", zip file "/data/user/0/com.example.applab/files/splitcompat/1/verified-splits/chitchat_dynamic_module.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.applab-aoTGwb4UiExHn2UP-1ioGA==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:125)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at com.example.chatapp.utility.ChitChat.initialize(ChitChat.java:83) 
        at com.example.chatapp_dynamic_module.DynamicActivity.startSecondPerson(DynamicActivity.java:53) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6304) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24803) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:794) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6651) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:824) 
        Suppressed: java.io.IOException: No original dex files found for dex location /data/app/com.example.applab-aoTGwb4UiExHn2UP-1ioGA==/split_config.en.apk
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:353)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:100)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:74)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:374)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:337)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:157)
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
        at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:64)
        at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:73)
        at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:88)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:69)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:35)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:695)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:729)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:956)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2282)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5722)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1685)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                ... 5 more
        Suppressed: java.io.IOException: No original dex files found for dex location /data/app/com.example.applab-aoTGwb4UiExHn2UP-1ioGA==/split_config.xhdpi.apk
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
2019-10-13 12:32:06.538 25730-25730/com.example.applab E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:353)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:100)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:74)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:374)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:337)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:157)
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
        at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:64)
        at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:73)
        at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:88)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:69)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:35)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:695)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:729)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:956)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2282)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5722)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1685)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                ... 5 more
```

Please help me to resolve the issue.

Comment: From the _crash report_ you posted, this line is the cause of your crash: _Didn't find class "com.applozic.mobicomkit.Applozic" on path:_ The rest of that line details the actual path. Perhaps the documentation for [ClassNotFoundException](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ClassNotFoundException) will help?

Comment: I saw the error cause. But this file is exist in one of my `aar` files. Dynamic module wants to access that class of imported `aar` module. Don't know why the error occurred

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39309773/java-lang-illegalstateexception-could-not-execute-method-for-androidonclick-an?rq=1
i am not sure, maye be work

Comment: This might happen due to missing or conflicted dependencies or improperly adding libs to project. Did you look into https://stackoverflow.com/a/9916751/1084174 ?